# how to set width div from begin to end of a browser width in html

Tags: html, css, width

I want to create a menu in html with a black background color so I set width of a div with 1360 px but it does not cover all over the page. Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

[image: Please See The Picture]

CSS:

```
*{
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    background-color:#ffffff;

    margin:0;

    direction:rtl;
}
#menu{
    background-color:#3d3d3d;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
}
#text_menu{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    float:right;
    margin-right:5px;
}
#text_menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:10px;
}
 #text_menu ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 #text_menu ul li a{
     text-decoration:none;
     padding:5px;
     color:#fff;
     transition:all ease-out .4s;
     -moz-transition:all ease-out .4s;
      -webkit-transition:all ease-out .4s;
       -o-transition:all ease-out .4s;

 }
 #text_menu ul li:hover a{
     height:50px;
     width:100%;
     color:#b6ff00;
 }
 #header{
     align-content:center;
     height:464px;
     width:80%;
     background-image:url(../images/1.jpg);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

Html :

```
<body>
    <div style=" height:155px"></div>
    <div id="menu"> 
        <div id="text_menu">
    <ul><b>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
</b>
</ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:50px"></div>
    <div align="center" style=" width:100%">
        <div id="header" align="center">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the body margin to 0

Then set the width of your menu to 100%

Comment: Set the body margin to 0

Then set the width of your header to 100%   : It does not work

Comment: are you putting another content atop of your menu

Answer (score 0):

Just do this with your menu

HTML:

```
<div class='menu'>
    <!-- menu Items and stuff here -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you are putting this menu inside another div, then make sure that it also has a width of 100%, else this will not work.

Comment: .menu {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
} it does not work again

Comment: Try setting the body's margin and padding to 0 too.
body { margin:0; padding:0;}